# Media key shortcuts ceased to function

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently (say within the last two months), some of my media keys have ceased to obey their assigned shortcut.

Take, for example, Play. If I assign AudioPlay as the keyboard binding in the Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts menu, nothing happens when I press the key (this at least suggests that the the key is still recognized).

Further, if I assign another shortcut (e.g., Ctrl-Alt-slash), this works as expected, which suggests it is still possible to assign a shortcut to the play function.

This seems to be related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486182/volume-control-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-14-04) question over on AskUbuntu, but the accepted solution (mess around with `gsettings`) does not apply, as the suspected lack of `XF86` is not true in my case (at least in `gsettings`).

It may be worth noting that there *is* a discrepancy along these lines in my Keyboard Shortcut interface--namely, the media keys that still work (e.g., Mute) list the `XF86` prefix in the shortcut menu, while those that don't work, don't have this prefix in this menu.

I've exhausted all other avenues of exploration that came to mind, including the [suggested](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rebecca_cinnamon.php) `cinnamon-desktop-migrate-mediakeys` which came along with the 17.1 release (this problem started well after I upgraded to 17.1).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Excellent - this was exactly my problem. Google Play Music chrome extension had hijacked the keys. I deleted the extension (didn't really need it after all) and everything is back to normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very possible that you have a Chrome extension hijacking those keys -- for example, Plex or Google Play.

To investigate, head over to chrome://extensions/, and check out the "Keyboard shortcuts" link at the bottom of the page -- investigate to see which keys may be prioritized by Chrome extensions, e.g.:

[image: plex hijacker]

Here, it's clear to see that Plex has taken control of the Media Play/Pause, Media Next Track, Media Previous Track, and Media Stop buttons. Simply click the `X` next to each to un-set that shortcut entirely, or reset the scope to `In Chrome` if you'd still like those shortcuts to work while a Chrome window is activated. An alternative is to just turn off the extension itself.

The following links helped with this answer: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-chrome-hijacking-media-keys-heres/,  http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/

Comment: Hmm. Plex is no longer hijacking, but the keys stopped working all of a sudden again. Maybe there's a way to query which program is hijacking the keys?

Comment: Just restarted and I have control back, even after starting Chrome. The mystery continues.

Comment: The "Keyboard shortcuts" option is now in the Extensions menu in newer versions of Chrome.